# c# задача коммивояжера

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Решаю задачу коммивояжера методом ветвей и границ. Возникла загвоздка, она не столько связана с кодом, сколько с пониманием алгоритма. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С первыми двумя строками - все понятно, но возьмем, к примеру, 3 строку :

```
30, 0, М, 40, 0
```

В алгоритме написано

> для всех клеток матрицы с нулевыми элементами заменяем поочередно
>   нули на М

получаем :

```
30, М, М, 40, М
```

выходит, что минимальный элемент `= 30`, т.е `di=30`,  а в таблице же он равен `0`. Спрашивается, откуда `0` ?
Или мы заменяем, только первый `0` на `М`, а другой не трогаем, в случае, если в строке больше одного ?

Немного кода :

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        if (_Mass[i, j] == "0")
            _Mass[i, j] = (MinDi[i] + MinDj[j]).ToString();
```

Comment: п.с источник https://math.semestr.ru/kom/komm.php